# Activities (top left) does not work after some time in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

Tags: gnome

[image: Activities on top left]

Normally when I hover the cursor over it all windows are shown, with fave apps on the right & desktop windows on the left

After using a few apps, when I move the cursor over activities it doesn't work, nothing happens.

Only the top right tools are working. This happens frequently, and 
I have to reboot to restore the functionality.

Can someone tell me what the equivalent of restarting Windows Explorer is in Ubuntu GNOME?

Comment: after using which app(s)? If it's not caused by some setting (that might be changed by a particular app I suppose), then it seems like a bug, which should be reported on [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/)... Do you mean 17.04 or 17.10?

Comment: mostly I use firefox, but I don't think it will be the cause of a bug, Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: made a edit, I hope I'm more clear now

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of restarting Explorer.exe in GNOME would be if you press.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + (which means at the same time) <kbd>F2</kbd> 
Now you are going to get a box that looks like this come up without anything in it.

[image]

And type in `r` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

If that doesn't work then open a terminal or to a different tty and type in `gnome-shell --replace`

If you need to restart GDM which would log you out of your account, the command would be `systemctl restart gdm.service`

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround this issue , I installed Application menu in Gnome from software , & activities is replaced by Applications.
Sometimes it fails to show the overview on moving cursor to top left but clicking on Applications then Activities Overview makes it work again